# My try to prove this lemma: $H\trianglelefteq G \iff \exists\ \phi:G \to G'$ with $\phi$ a group homomorphism such that $\ker(\phi)=H.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I wanted to share with you the proof I made for this lemma (it has been given to us as an exercise to do on home). Here it goes:

> **Lemma:** Let $G$ be a group. Let $H \leq G$. Then:
>
> $H\trianglelefteq G \iff \exists\ \phi:G \to G'$ with $\phi$ a group homomorphism such that $\ker(\phi)=H.$

This is literally what we had been given to prove. I supposed that $G'$ is a group, because he didn't define it (maybe saying that $\phi$ was a group homomorphism is enough to define $G'$ as a group?).

My try

> **Proof:**
>
> $\Leftarrow\mid\ $ We know that $\ker(\phi)=H$. We have to see that $ghg^{-1}\in H$.
>
> $\phi(ghg^{-1}) = \phi(g)\phi(h)\phi(g)^{-1} = \phi(g)e'\phi(g)^{-1} = \phi(gg^{-1}) = \phi(e) = e'\in\ker(\phi)=H\text{, so  } H\trianglelefteq G .$
>
> $\Rightarrow\mid\ $ Suppose now that $H \trianglelefteq G.$
>   \begin{equation}
> H \trianglelefteq G\implies G\ /\ H\ \ \text{is a group, and}\ \pi: G \to G\ /\ H\ \ \text{is a group homomorphism}.
> \end{equation}
>   Furthermore, $\ker(\pi)=\{g\in G\mid \pi(g)=[e]\}=\{g\in G\mid [g]=[e]\}=H\ $,$\ $ because it has to happen that $Hg=He=H$, and this happens if and only if $g\in H$.

This is my try to prove this lemma. Is that proof correct? I would appreciate any comment with mistakes in my prove or hints to do it in another way.

**Edit:** I've corrected my mistakes, now I think that it's correct.

Thank you.

Comment: The second part is good! For the first part, you're assuming that H is normal in order to construct G/H in the first place, so you are really assuming what you want to prove. Instead, just take the given \phi:G\to G' with kernel H, and prove that H is normal.

Comment: Your concerns over what $G'$ is are justified.  $G'$ certainly can't be an arbitrary fixed group, because we can always take the trivial group (which has as kernel all of $G$).  It probably means that $G$ is fixed and you can choose any $G'$ and homomorphism $\varphi: G\rightarrow G'$.  As far as $G'$ being a group, it is enough to suppose that $G'$ has some binary operation defined on it (so saying it is a homomorphism actually has some content); then image of $\phi$ will inherit the properties of $G$ (but not necessarily all of $G'$ unless $\phi$ i onto).

Comment: @Abrahamlure I'm not so sure that those arrows should be going both ways. For example, if you know that $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$, can you necessarily say that $x = y$, for an arbitrary homomorphism $\phi$? Recall that an equivalent condition for normality of $H$ is that $g^{-1}hg \in H$ for any $h \in H$ and $g \in G$. Where would $\phi$ send such an element?

Comment: Remember that since $H = \text{ker }\phi$, for any $h \in H$, we have: $\phi(ghg^{-1}) = \phi(g)\phi(h)\phi(g)^{-1} = \phi(g)e'\phi(g)^{-1} = \phi(gg^{-1}) = \phi(e) = e'$, so that $ghg^{-1} \in \text{ker }\phi$

Comment: That's right, I'm sorry, I didn't notice that this was not an iff. I understood your proofs, thank you very much psj36, David Wheeler and Michael Cotton.

Comment: @Abrahamlure Even so your proof is not too well structured. To see that gH = Hg for all g in G, let g be an element of G and k in gH. Then show that k is in Hg. This shows one containment. Then do the reverse. (David Wheeler's is correct, of course, but doing it this way will teach you more about how cosets work.)